# Eagle: How do I make a component from a board?

Tags: components, layout, eaglecad, library

I recently discovered the fantastic Arduino shield components in LadyAda's latest Eagle library. Now of course I'd like to make my own, using the mechanical layer from an existing Eagle board file. But the Google has been unhelpful on this topic. And my fumbling around has not unearthed any obvious affordances for copying a drawing from a board editing window to a component editing window. (I have made some simple components starting from the pads of an existing component, following one of the many tutorials that explain THAT process.)

How do I make a component footprint from an existing board drawing?

Comment: There used to be an ULP on the cadsoft ULP page that created a library file (containing all used components) from a board file. I don't recall the name, but once you know it is there you can probably find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used 2 different methods for scavenging components out of Eagle projects.

**Automated method.**  Run `exp-project-lbr.ulp`, then sort through the automatically generated library.

**Manual method.**  Originally from [here](https://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?t=8290).

1. Select the parts you want to copy with the group select tool.
2. Use the scissors button on the toolbar.
3. Right-click the group or hit the GO button after clicking the cut button. Eagle wants to know what it is you wish to "cut", which is really more like the "copy" command in most apps.
4. Open the new file and do a paste, it should copy the info.

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! Not exactly what I'd call an intuitive use of the Mac OS X clipboard...

Comment: @KaelinColclasure  Glad it worked.  UI in Eagle makes everything not exactly intuitive.